# jQuery .post not always running

Tags: jquery, timeout, .post

I'm creating a site that would allow a user to select one of any number of answers. Ultimately, I've got it all working to a point. The system works, but the submit doesn't seem to work if a user is on the page for over 30 seconds. There's no timeout set that should be causing this on the site, and I can't seem to find what would cause it in the jQuery .post. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
function submitAns(str, num) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName(str);
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            $.post('saveAnswer.aspx', {
                'answer': String(radios[i].value),
                'question': num,
                'comment': String($("#comment").val())
            }, function (msg) {
                if (msg == "failed") {
                    jAlert('Error Saving Data.');
                } else {
                    window.location = "Voting-Page";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is hit after the user clicks on a button for a form that looks similar to this:

```
<input type='radio' name='group0' value='Yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' name='group0' value='No'>No
<textarea id='comment' rows='7' cols='40'></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" onclick="submitAns('group0','0');" class="btnSubmit" />
```

If I submit the form within the 30 second time frame it goes through without any problem. Otherwise, the page is reloaded and the form isn't submitted. I've tried adding a large timeout to the .post by adding `'timeout': 300000`, but that still didn't work. I also tried removing the jAlert and checking for any site errors (none found). What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you checked your JS console for errors?

Comment: is there a form in the page

Comment: which browser is used to test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see is there is a `submit` button in your page, the default action of the the submit button is to submit the form, to prevent it you can return `false` from the `onclick` event handler.

But what puzzles me is, in this case it has to consistent, the 30 second part does not have any effect here.

Any way try changing the `onclick` handler in  submit button to

```
<input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" onclick="submitAns('group0','0'); return false;" class="btnSubmit" />
```